# GPU version of GrabCut

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

Does anyone know if there's a GPU version of GrabCut? I can't quite seem to find a GrabCut module in `opencv_contrib`. Can GrabCut only be run on CPU?

Answer (score 1):

I think the GPU version was removed from CUDA release cycle 7. So it's not available right now.